# One-Way Syncing from PostgreSQL to Android with connected Tables

Tags: android, database, postgresql, database-design, synchronization

i'm planning to create an Android App which has a partial database-state of the PostrgeSQL in the local SqLite database. Imagine you've got a table for friends and a table for their comments. On the android device i've stored my friends an the comments from them. The comments have a foreign key for friends. Now i delete an friend from an other device an add an other one. The number of my friends and the comments i need on the device didn't change and i only recognize a change in the friends table via delta synchronization.

Is there a way (or already built-in possibility) to synchronize such partial database-states without hardcoding the dependencies?

Thanks :)

Comment: check out symmetricds

Comment: So you want to do some kind of lazy foreign key cascades at sync time?

Comment: Yes , thats a what i need. I'm focusing on low trafic, therefore i do not want to send all pk's on the device to the Server.